# Identify the row in query that causes an error?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have done some reading and looking at people having similar issues but just narrowing scope down by using TOP to find the issue manually.

This is what I have done in the past to find offending records.

I was wondering if there is something more robust which can be used more universally.

I have a query which is:

```
; WITH x AS ( SELECT b.ParentPartId,
                  b.ChildPartId,
                  b.ChildPartQty,
                  b.ConsumingWorkCenterId
           FROM jbds.BoM b
           UNION ALL
           SELECT lb.ParentPartId,
                  lb.ChildPartId,
                  lb.ChildPartQty,
                  lb.ConsumingWorkCenterId
           FROM jbds.BoM lb
           INNER JOIN x ON lb.ParentPartId = x.ChildPartId ) 
SELECT *
FROM x
WHERE ConsumingWorkCenterId IS NULL
```

The error I get is:

> Msg 530, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

I know you could use TOP and eventually find the offending record but I was wondering if there is better solution to using TOP instead of going slowly through the records?

Comment: My idea: Disable the recursion limit, add a column that tracks the recursion level, then filter on `level > 100`.

Comment: @usr Thank you. That is the solution for my issue above and I've voted you up for it. Just wondering if there is universal solution to other errors within SQL such as displaying all records up the error.

Comment: Depending on the scenerio, perhaps create a loop that processes a group of records at a time, and log which records are processed, a flag, a table, a variable with the highest ID processed. Then avoid them on the next pass, check the log when it crashes.

Comment: It can be a infinite loop caused by a wrong `JOIN` for the connecting fields, a loop in the data, or really more level than the maximum recursion allowed, that IMO is the first thing to check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea: Disable the recursion limit, add a column that tracks the recursion level, then filter on `level > 100`.

> Just wondering if there is universal solution to other errors within SQL such as displaying all records up the error.

No general solution here. The query processor can produce a variety of plans, many of which do not have a clear "order of records" or notion of the first point where an error occurs. As records travel through the pipeline they are often incomplete and do not correspond to what you wrote.

Tracking errors in queries is a common request (think of DML failing mid-way - no indication where the error is). Unfortunately, no good solution here. Best advice I have is to avoid dangerous patterns in query plans. Which is easier said then done.

Answer (score 1):

Tracking the recursion level won't solve this issue. 
To recreate the error, I wrote this code:

```
drop table #temp 
GO
create table #temp (
    ParentPartId int,
    ChildPartId int
)
GO

truncate table #temp
GO
insert into #temp(ParentPartId,ChildPartId)
values (1,2),(2,3),(3,1)
GO

;WITH x AS ( 
    SELECT 
        b.ParentPartId,
        b.ChildPartId
    FROM #temp b
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        lb.ParentPartId,
        lb.ChildPartId
    FROM #temp lb
    INNER JOIN x 
        ON lb.ParentPartId = x.ChildPartId 
) 
SELECT 
    *
FROM x
```

If you track recursion, you'll find that at level 101 the values will be (2,3). But it doesn't mean, that there's something wrong with this row. There's a circural chain of parent-child references in your table, but the query can break at any of the records, not necessarilly on that which is logically incorect.

To solve this, you first need to fix your query. You're missing a condition for "static" part of CTE (before the UNION). You need to limit the rows in this part to leafs (bottom-top approach), or roots (top-bottom approach), that is rows that have no further children (first approach) or no parents (second approach).

This way the query won't break, and it will not list records, that have it's predecessors linked as parents. Also, rows wont be listed multiple times in results. 
Then, you'll have to join the cte to original table to check what records from table are not listed in cte - these will be rows you're looking for.